# Problema con float: left;

Tags: html, css, css3

tengo un problema con el diseño de una web de prueba que estoy realizando.
El problema es que a dos contenedores(un aside y un section) les aplico la propiedad de `float: left;` pero se ubican uno debajo del otro. Aquí la imagen y el css de cada uno:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CSS:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

*{margin:0; padding:0}

@media (orientation: landscape)
{
  #alien1
  {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color: #00ff00;
  }

  #alien2
  {
    background-color: #00ff00;
    color: #ff0000;
  }

  #alien3
  {
    background-color: #0000ff;
    color: #ff8000;
  }

  #alien4
  {
    background-color: #ffff00;
    color: #c471cd;
  }

  .alien
  {
    padding: 1vh 1vw;
    margin: 1vh 1vw;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  #barranav
  {
    background-color: #ff00ff;
    width: 39vw;
    font-size: 1vw;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  #barralateral
  {
    background-color: #d08030;
    float: left;
    height: 100.5vh;
    width: 15vw;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  #infoprincipal
  {
    background-color: #9900ff;
    height: 100.5vh;
    width: 82.8vw;
    float: left;
  }

  #piedepagina
  {
    background-color: #00f12f;
    height: 100%;
    width: 98.5vw;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  #imagengameplay
  {
    padding-left: 20px;
    width: 80vw;
    height: 80vh;
    display: inline;
  }

  #titulo-infoprincipal
  {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }

  #saludo
  {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 1vh;
    font-size: 2vw;
    display: inline;
  }
```

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="description" content="pagina de prueba"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="html5, css3, JavaScript, diseño web"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no"/>

    <title>Pagina de prueba</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles1.css"/>

  </head>
  <body>

    <header>

      <h1><mark><em>Hola que hace</em></mark></h1>

    </header>

    <nav id="barranav">
      <a href="web2.html" id="alien1" class="alien"><cite><strong>Alienigenas1</strong></cite></a>
      <a href="web3.html" id="alien2" class="alien"><cite><strong>Alienigenas2</strong></cite></a>
      <a href="web4.html" id="alien3" class="alien"><cite><strong>Alienigenas3</strong></cite></a>
      <a href="index2.html" id="alien4" class="alien"><cite><strong>Alienigenas4</strong></cite></a>
    </nav>

    <aside id="barralateral">
      <p class="elemento">Primer elemento</p>
      <p class="elemento">Segundo elemento</p>
      <p class="elemento">Tercer elemento</p>
      <p class="elemento">Primer elemento</p>
      <p class="elemento">Segundo elemento</p>
      <p class="elemento">Tercer elemento</p>
      <p class="elemento">Primer elemento</p>
      <p class="elemento">Segundo elemento</p>
      <p class="elemento">Tercer elemento</p>
      <p class="elemento">Primer elemento</p>
      <p class="elemento">Segundo elemento</p>
      <p class="elemento">Tercer elemento</p>
      <p class="elemento">Primer elemento</p>
      <p class="elemento">Segundo elemento</p>
      <p class="elemento">Tercer elemento</p>
      <p class="elemento">Primer elemento</p>
      <p class="elemento">Segundo elemento</p>
      <p class="elemento">Tercer elemento</p>
      <p class="elemento">Primer elemento</p>
      <p class="elemento">Segundo elemento</p>
      <p class="elemento">Tercer elemento</p>
    </aside>

    <section id="infoprincipal">

      <h2 id="titulo-infoprincipal">Gameplay</h2>

      <img id="imagengameplay" src="https://i2.wp.com/culturageek.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Culturageek.com_.ar-Battlefield-5.jpg?fit=1200%2C800">
      <br>
      <p id="saludo">Hey muy buenas a todos aqui estamos en un nuevo gameplay</p>

    </section>

    <footer id="piedepagina">

      <time class="infolegal" datetime="2019/02/04" pubdate>Publicado el día 2019/02/04</time>
      <small class="infolegal">Contacto: nicogamer925@gmail.com</small>
      <small class="infolegal"><strong>Derechos reservados por narnia</strong></small>

    </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola. Ha faltado que indiques como esperas el resultado amigo.

Comment: Ese es todo el CSS ? no reseteaste los margenes que por defecto tienen los navegadores?

Comment: Ese es el de los contenedores. Discúlpame soy novato con css, ¿Puedes decirme como hacer eso de resetear los margenes?

Comment: Ya agregue el css completo. Haber si se te ocurre algo.

Comment: Ya lo agregue. : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ElAlien123, el comportamiento que obtienes es el normal al usar float, pues está pensado para que el texto en bloque fluya alrededor de imágenes. Evita usarlo para otros fines que no sean ese.

Tienes 3 métodos para crear columnas de forma más efectiva que usando float:

1. Replicar una tabla
2. Usar elementos inline-block
3. Usar flexbox

**Replica de tabla:**

```css
aside, main {
display: table-cell;
padding: 10px;
vertical-align: top;
}
aside{
width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<aside>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

</aside>
<main>
<img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/" width="100%">
</main>
```

**Inline Block**

```css
main {
font-size: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
}
aside, section {
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px;
vertical-align: top;
font-size: 1rem;
white-space: normal;
}
aside{
width: 20%;
}
section {
width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<main>
<aside>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</aside>
<section>
<img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/" width="100%">
</section>
</main>
```

**Flexbox**

```css
main {
display: flex;
}
aside, section {
padding: 10px;
vertical-align: top;
}
aside{
width: 20%;
}
section {
width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<main>
<aside>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</aside>
<section>
<img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/" width="100%">
</section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto puede ocasionar los valores de `margin` y `padding` que los navegadores tienen por defecto, debería `setearlos` a 0 *(como solución más próxima)* , antes de añadir los estilos correspondientes.

Esto se logra con el comodín `*` *(asterisco)* para seleccionar todos los elementos del `DOM`

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0}

#barralateral
{
  background-color: #d08030;
  float: left;
  height: 100.5vh;
  width: 15vw;
  overflow: auto;
}

#infoprincipal
{
  background-color: #9900ff;
  height: 100.5vh;
  width: 82.8vw;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="barralateral">
</div>
<div id="infoprincipal">
</div>
```

Otra opción más sencilla sería utilizar `flexbox` para crear las dos columnas. Para manejar el ancho solo modificaría el `max-width` del contenedor izquierdo.

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0}
#padre {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
#barralateral{
 background:red;
 flex :1 ;
 height: 100vh;
 max-width: 20%;
}
#infoprincipal{
 background:yellow;
 flex :1 ;
 height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="padre">
  <div id="barralateral" class="hijo">
  </div>
  <div id="infoprincipal">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sigue sin funcionar

Comment: No entiendo cual es el problema. Debería funcionar

Comment: @ElAlien123 funciona en el ejemplo de mi respuesta. Igual añadí otra opción con flexbox por si acaso ;)

Comment: Intentare implementarlo lo mejor que pueda para que todo quede en orden.